# Optional dependencies injections best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, nuget

I'v made a .net class library, it's function is to create a identity users and add all necessary in methods and dependencies (email verifications, google and facebook logins, roles, ...) in just one line of `services.AddMyCoreIdentity(options=>{...})`, and package it into a nuget package

Okay all good, but  sometimes i don't need email verification in my project and I disable it in the `options=>{...}`   line, but how can I prevent the injection of the email service dependency in my package when i don't need it,

Is that even possible?

Comment: The purpose of injecting dependencies is that you have everything a class needs to run.  Perhaps you should have an empty implementation to inject, but it would suggest potentially the design of your classes could be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of using an `options => …` mechanism, you define a fluent interface in which you can do something like:

```
services
    .AddMyCoreIdentity() // Only adds common services that are always used
    .AddEmail() // Only adds the Email service
    .AddXXX() // Whichever other service that is not always used
```

Hope it helps!